# Наложение текста один на другой

Tags: python, pygame

Подскажите пожалуйста почему я не могу (где ошибка) наложить текст так чтобы он четко лежал друг на друге, а через пробелы верхнего просвечивался нижний. 
Вот как получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А так должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю что из-за разнице в длине пробелов и букв это происходит. 
Скрипт уменьшать не буду так как это поможет советчику быстрее разобраться с проблемой.

```
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([600, 400])
pygame.display.set_caption('English sound v.1')
keepGoing = True
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 60)

words =["sophisticated"]
letters =["po","ow","ph","ou","ed","com", "ful"]

def print_text (font, x, y, words, letters, color = (255,255,255)):
    RED = (255,0,0)
    spis_1 = []
    spis_2 = []

    for word_1 in words:
        for letter in letters:
            spis_1 = word_1

    for word_2 in words:
        for letter in letters:
            if len (letter) == 2:
                colorful = "  "
            if len (letter) == 3:
                colorful = "   "
            if len (letter) == 4:
                colorful = "    "
            word_2 = word_2.replace(letter, colorful)
            spis_2 = word_2

    text_image_2 = font.render(spis_1, True, RED)
    screen.blit(text_image_2, (x,y))

    text_image = font.render(spis_2, True, color)
    screen.blit(text_image, (x,y))

while keepGoing:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:

                print_text(font, 205, 255, words,letters)

    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Рекомендую добавить картинку ожидаемого результата и скриншот текущего поведения скрипта, это может ускорить получение ответа

Comment: А ещё лучше удалить из скрипта всё, что не касается вопроса, и оставить только собственно рисование текста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Дёшево и сердито**

Используйте моноширинный шрифт. У таких шрифтов ширина любого символа (включая пробелы и знаки препинания) фиксированная, а значит, позиции символов второй строки будут точно совпадать с позициями символов первой. Под Windows стандартные моноширинные шрифты - Courier New и Lucida Console. Если они не устраивают, можно найти в интернете другие. Вообще, я бы посоветовал вам всегда явно указывать имя шрифта, а лучше - грузить его из файла. `pygame.font.SysFont(None, 60)` может быть различным на разных системах. Например, у вас это Times New Roman, а у меня - Arial.

**Дорого и со вкусом**

Если моноширинные шрифты вас не устраивают, то нужно рендерить строку с пробелами посимвольно, вычисляя `x` для каждого символа при помощи метода [`Font.size()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.size). Этот метод возвращает размеры в пикселях изображения, которое получится при рендеринге переданной ему строки этим шрифтом. Соответственно, `x` для каждого символа будет равен ширине строки, идущей перед ним, плюс базовое смещение всей надписи.